# Did Iranians kill "the scientist who helped the US"?

Tags: donald-trump, iran

> Many people are saying that the Iranians killed the scientist who helped the U.S. because of Hillary Clinton's hacked emails.
>   [11:45 PM - 8 Aug 2016 Trump](https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump/status/762781826549030912)

Is it true that many people are saying this? And did "Iranians [kill] the scientist who helped the U.S."?

<sup>(Whether this was "because" of Clinton's hacked emails is a motivation question, that I understand is [off-topic](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here).)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

It is uncontested that Iran executed a scientist, Shahram Amiri. ([CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2016/08/07/middleeast/iran-nuclear-scientist-executed/))

[Vox](http://www.vox.com/2016/8/9/12410882/clinton-emails-trump-iranian-scientist-executed-amiri) describes two sources that Vox thinks could be interpreted to claim a link between Clinton's emails and the execution of the Iranian scientist: [this interview on CBS](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/face-the-nation-transcripts-august-7-2016-flake-cotton/), and [this tweet by the Drudge Report](https://twitter.com/DRUDGE_REPORT/status/762364610187898881).

Vox has inferred that when Trump said "many people" that he meant these two sources.

## Summary

At least two people/organizations, in Vox's estimation, have suggested this connection that Mr. Trump says "many people" are claiming.

Iran did execute a scientist.

Comment: Had that executed scientist "helped the US"? Also I'm having trouble finding anything about emails in that (very long) interview transcript, can you include a relevant quote?